# Running Dart App on Heroku

Tags: heroku, dart

I am following [this blog](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/08/running-dart-in-cloud-with-heroku.html) to upload a Dart app to Heroku and run it.  I have gotten to the point where the app is successfully deployed to Heroku, but the app is not running.  The following is from the Heroku logs:

```
2012-12-20T18:04:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `dart TestApp.dart`
2012-12-20T18:04:57+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: dart: command not found
2012-12-20T18:04:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2012-12-20T18:04:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The following is the contents of my `Procfile`

```
web: dart TestApp.dart
```

Can anyone point me towards a solution to this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have forgotten to add the *buildpack* to the config. See the [getting started of Heroku Buildpack for Dart](https://github.com/igrigorik/heroku-buildpack-dart#getting-started).

Basically, you have to use the following commands :

```
$> heroku create myapp_name -s cedar
$> heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/igrigorik/heroku-buildpack-dart.git
```

**WARNING** : With the last version of buildpack it seems `dart` command is no more in the `PATH`. A workaround is to use the full path in `Procfile`:

```
web: ./dart-sdk/bin/dart TestApp.dart
```

Comment: I had previously added the buildpack to the config and I tried to add it again to be sure, but my app still fails with the same error.

Comment: I just test with a fresh install and got the same error you have :-/ My old install was working. Sorry !